# Version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, libstdc++

I have built a C++ app on a VM Ubuntu 16.04 on which I have installed g++ compiler 6.2.0 in order to support C++14 features. When I tried to run it on new clean VM 16.04 which has default the g++ 5.4.0 the error  **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found** pops up.
I've noticed that on the VM with the updated compiler library libstdc++.so.6.0.22 has been installed. On the clean VM I'd like to avoid to update the compiler so I tried to install only the latest libstdc++6 package. However the library that was installed was libstdc++.so.6.0.21 and so the problem persisted. How can I install specifically the libstdc++.so.6.0.22 version?

Comment: Link everything besides libc statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) to make sure only the packages you want are updated to a newer version.

Alternatively, you could simply compile your program with g++ 5.4, because according to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14), this compiler already supports all c++14, the only difference is that g++-6 defaults to *-std=c++14*, whereas with g++-5 you have to set the language standard explicitly.

Comment: Well, that's surely not the only difference though between GCC 5 and GCC 6 in terms of C++14.

Answer (score 60):

You need to upgrade libstdc++6 to latest version like this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
sudo apt-get upgrade libstdc++6
```

After that you can check if you get GLIBCXX desired version like this:

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

Comment: For others: if the command `add-apt-repository` fails you like it failed me, follow the instructions here (replace `precise` with your ubuntu version): https://askubuntu.com/a/193520/376175